# Webfaction Access to font at domain/fonts/fontname.ext from origin 'http://mydomain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, fonts, webfaction

I have django 2.1.5 with python3.7 app worket well on local...

I have create static app in my webfaction dashboard Static-Only (no .htaccess).
All work fine except certains fonts
i have this message this error in my browser:

Access to font at

> 'http://domain/static/plugins/elegant_font/html_css/fonts/ElegantIcons.woff'
>   from origin 'http://domain' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource.
>       (index):942 GET http://domain/static/plugins/elegant_font/html_css/fonts/ElegantIcons.woff net::ERR_FAILED**

How can i solved it i have trying many solution (django-cors-headers and others)
But not work.
I need if possible step by step help ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved your issue by now.

From my experience just make sure the ***webfaction static app*** is in the same website/domain group as your ***webfaction django/mod_wsgi*** app (like the screenshot below):

[image: Webfaction control panel, django website with separate static & media apps]

I followed the following instructions from the [Webfaction Documentation](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/getting-started.html).